# jsf core + plupload + jquery editor

Tags: jquery, jsf, plupload

I have a jsf web page which contains these component :

1. jsf tag h:textedit which worked in ajax , it an autocomplete component
2. a jQuery editor
3. plupload (jQuery image upload plugin)

This page sometimes work, and sometimes not. And when it doesn't work, I have to wait some second and refresh then it works.
When I make in a page only jQuery editor + plupload, everything works fine.

Comment: what part of the page doesn't work? And maybe post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the jQuery editor .
I change it for some tinyMCE, and everything going fine.